# Can we instantiate interface nested inside the class in java and why it is different from kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm currently learning Android Development and I come across the code where an object for an anonymous class having a nested interface in it is instantiated.

**JAVA CODE**
[image: java code for the above statement.]

**KOTLIN CODE**
[image: kotlin code for the above statem]

In this code an Object listner of anonymous class is being made from Parent.Hello() where Parent is super class and interface Hello is nested in it. As we have learned that interfaces cannot be instantiated then how the code is working and legal. Also why Parent.Hello() is used why not Parent.Hello as its kotlin counterpart.

Comment: In both cases, you are _implementing_ the interface using an anonymous class. That's why you have to override the method and provide an implementation. And then you're creating an instance of the anonymous class at the same time.

Comment: Also, in Kotlin, when a function has no (meaningful) return value, you should make the return type `Unit` (typically accomplished by not explicitly writing the return type, as that defaults to `Unit`) instead of `Void`.

Comment: Please keep in mind for future questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 3):

In the Java example as well as in the Kotlin example you do not instantiate interface `Parent.Hello`, but you instantiate an **anonymous class** that implements interface `Parent.Hello`.

[Anonymous classes in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

[Anonymous objects in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html)

In Kotlin, you write `Person.Hello` and not `Person.Hello()` because interface `Person.Hello` does not have a constructor. Java on the other hand does not care for that distinction.